# How to detect up or down direction jQuery UI datepicker at his input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I can detect input offset position at window:
input.getBoundingClientRect().top
But I must to know where will be my datepicker block(under input or above it) to change it class-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
    var instHeight = 0;

    setTimeout(function () {
      instHeight = inst.dpDiv.height();
      if(input.getBoundingClientRect().top < instHeight) {
        inst.dpDiv
          .removeClass('ui-top')
          .addClass('ui-bottom')
          .position({
            my: 'left top+5',
            at: 'left bottom',
            collision: 'none',
            of: input
          })
      } else {
        inst.dpDiv
          .removeClass('ui-bottom')
          .addClass('ui-top')
          .position({
            my: 'left bottom-5',
            at: 'left top',
            collision: 'none',
            of: input
          })
      }
    },0);
  },
```

Comment: The `if` condition might need a change. When there is enough space above the input but not enough space below the input, the `if` code still does not get executed, which it should.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way for catching the position of opened calendar-box, is the listening click event. After catch the datepicker input and datepicker calendar-box offset position from top.

[There is an jsfiddle example for how to use with multiple datepickers](https://jsfiddle.net/7czkp5sn/5/)

Step 1: catching the calendar-box, after DOM init `$('#ui-datepicker-div')`

Step 2: Catch click to datepicker input.

Step 3: Catching position of both (calendar-box and datepicker input) elements from offset top.

Step 4: After catching position of elements, you can manipulate type of actions whatever you want. In this case we add classes, but you can call a function, `input.offsetTop <= calendarBox.offsetTop ? toUpFunction() : toDownFunction()`

Hope it helps.

Good luck!